# Is it possible to use annyang for speech recognition in cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, annyang

I'm trying to use annyang for speech recognition in my cordova app. I'm following [Talater's](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) and [Alex's](http://alexpgates.com/blog/2013/09/annyang-js-and-speak-js) examples, but I cannot get it to work.

I noticed that it doesn't ask me for permission using my microphone.

I'm testing the code in laptop's Chrome, not in device.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <!-- <script src="js/speakClient.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.6.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/annyang.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/annyang.js"></script>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
// Language select
annyang.setLanguage('es-ES');

if (annyang) {

  var sayThis = function(repeat) {
    alert(repeat);
  }

  // Let's define a command.
  var commands = {
    '*repeat': sayThis
  };
  // Debug info for the console
  annyang.debug();

  // Initialize annyang with our commands
  annyang.init(commands);

  // Start listening.
  annyang.start();
}
else {
  alert("No annyang");
}
```

Please, tell me if I'm missing something (If not possible to make it work in cordova app, How can I use speech recognition in a cordova app meant to work in iPhone?)

Comment: chrome API and iOS API for microphone are not the same, you should try this in real/emulated device http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureAudioOptions

Comment: Ok, later I'll give it a try in device, but I think it'll be the same ;)

Comment: Did you solve the question? Can you share with me? :/

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get annyang.js to work in my Ionic (Cordova) app on Android devices. It's freaking amazing.

The problem is that for the Android platform, Cordova bundles an Android browser by default. However, Chrome is the only browser that currently supports Speech Recognition API. http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition

The key is bundling a **Chromium webview through Crosswalk**. Since Chrome is not available on iOS, this solution does not work with iOS. For Ionic applications, type in the following commands to add Crosswalk.

New Project:

```
npm install ionic -g
ionic start my_app
cd my_app
ionic browser add crosswalk
ionic run android
```

Previous Ionic Project:

```
npm install ionic -g
cd existing_app
ionic browser add crosswalk
ionic run android
```

reference: http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

Then install "cordova-media-plugin" get permission to access Android's RECORD_AUDIO. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
```

That's all.

On a sidenote, you might want to try it out with an Angular wrapper for Annyang (version 1.5) available here: https://github.com/levithomason/angular-annyang

All links mentioned above were accessed October 22, 2015

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: @Ghost alright, just added the specific commands for adding Crosswalk

Comment: So, this solution does not work on ios devices? Right?

Comment: @SinsubJeong Hi, when you deploy into a real android phone, is it working? mine is not.

Comment: My code worked with an actual Android phone at the time of writing. Since then I'm no longer working on an Annyang project. Should work fine, I think.